Issues with Server-Sent Events and Delays Using Flask and JavaScript
I'm working on a web application using Flask for the backend and JavaScript for the frontend, employing Server-Sent Events (SSE) to manage real-time data updates. However, I am experiencing unexpected delays and repetitive message display issues. Every 10 seconds it shows 10 messages all at once not one per second.
Below is my JavaScript client-side code and a hypothetical Flask server-side setup.
Client-side JavaScript:
<script>
    var userId = {{ user_id|tojson }};
    const eventSource = new EventSource("/stream");
    eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
        const messageContent = `<div class="${message.me === userId ? 'message me' : 'message'}">
                                    <div class="bubble">${message.text}</div>
                                    <div class="time">${message.time}</div>
                                </div>`;
        document.querySelector(".message-content").innerHTML += messageContent;
    };

    function sendMessage(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const input = document.querySelector(".message-form input[type='text']");
        const message = input.value.trim();
        if (message !== "") {
            fetch("/send_message", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ message: message })
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Failed to send message");
                }
                input.value = ""; // Clear input field after sending message
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }
    }
</script>

Server-side Flask (Hypothetical):
with open('msg','r') as file:
    messages = eval(file.read() + ']')
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def y():
        while True:
            yield 'data: ' + dumps(messages[-1]) + '\n\n'
            sleep(1)
    return Response(y(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
@app.route('/send_message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    message = {'text':request.json.get('message'),'time':datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),'me':current_user.id}
    messages.append(message)
    with open('msg','a') as file:
        file.write(str(message) + ',')
    socketio.emit('new_message', message, broadcast=True)
    return jsonify({'status': 'success'})

msg file:
[{'text': 'Welcome', 'time': '04:32:13', 'me': 'sadra'}


why do you label your flask code as Hypothetical? Is that NOT the code you use? If not, then how is it possible to fix your issue if you don't show the code with the issue?

It's because this isn't my full code. You can simply ignore that part.

OK, so which code do you have an issue with? I don't know python well enough, but all my server SSE code flushes the output after each "event"
